# Geometrical shape of level curve

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $A, B$ be two distinct points in the Euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. Describe geometrically the level sets of the mapping $f(M)=\frac{AM}{BM}$.

My reasoning so far:

Except in a degenerate case, $ABM$ is a triangle. So $\frac{AM}{BM}$ is the ratio between two sides of a triangle. But I don't know how to describe the level sets geometrically.

Comment: They are circles. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_circles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let$ f(M)  = \tau $ a constant for a level curve.

If angle at M is bisected internally the constant ratio locus is called the ***Apollonian Circle.***

To locate this point bipolar coordinates are convenient.

[Const $\tau$ curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_coordinates#:%7E:text=Bipolar%20coordinates%20are%20a%20two,based%20on%20the%20Apollonian%20circles.&text=However%2C%20the%20term%20bipolar%20coordinates,curves%2C%20such%20as%20elliptic%20coordinates.) have this ratio maintained constant.

We can make a simple construction and  look to the intersection of Apollonian circle with x-axis at M1. The second point of intersection is for the the external angle bisector at M2.

The Apollonian Circle has its diameter as $M1-M2$ as shown.

Note that constant  $\tau $ locus of level curve  permits M to be ***anywhere on the two green bisectors*** shown due to the property

$$\dfrac{AM_{int}}{M_{int}B}=\dfrac{AM_{ext}}{M_{ext}B}=\tau.$$

[image]